# Language resources files not loaded in class library on other environment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, resx

I have a class library project (c#, .net 4.0). It has some WPF user controls which show content in english or spanish according to the culture configured in database.

For doing so, in the main window constructor, I receive a CultureInfo parameter, which I use to set the culture to be used in my Localization namespace, like this:

```
public MainWindow(Entities.TransactionContext transactionContext, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Localization.Resources.Culture = culture;

            InitializeComponent();

            //Some other unrelated code here
        }
```

That is used from the main program wich calls my dll. In there, a query is made to get the default culture. It can be either "en-US" or "es-MX", then it is send as the second parameter. The first one is not important for now.

As I said, I have a namespace named MyProject.Localization (I'm changing my project name since internal policies, you understand). In that folder, I have three resources files:

- Resources.resx
- Resources.en-US.resx
- Resources.es-MX.resx

Default entries in Resources.resx have values in spanish since, you know, I'm mexican.

Also, in my code, when I need to show a message or set a label text, I use something like this:

```
this.lblStatusMessage.Content = Localization.Resources.OperationCancelled;
```

In this example: "OperationCancelled" is an entry that exists in all the resources files. In spanish its value is "Operación Cancelada" and in english it says "Operation Cancelled".

After all this story, this works great in my development environment. I run my test project, I see it in english, then I change the language in database, run it again and boom! spanish.

But.

When I commit changes to this project via SVN, it is then deployed to QA environment by some automated process (it's awesome). And then I test there and I always see the contents in spanish (as the default ones). Even when I change the language on the QA database, it always shows labels and messages in spanish.

I tried some options:

Changed the resources dll's Build Action to Resource instead of Embedded Resource. It didn't work.

Right click->Properties, Resources tab shows no Resources, so I created three resx files there and set custom namespace as MyProject.Localization. Next I excluded my original files since now there was some ambiguity errors. Again it worked in my dev machine but in QA didn't.

Any ideas about this? My hipothesis is that it has something to do with the resx files, maybe they're not included in the final built or something like that, and that's why the app cannot get the localized texts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at the end it was simple.

This is my explanation, maybe it's incomplete, but I understood it like that and worked for me.

When you use resources files for localization and you build the solution, VS creates a DLL for each of them. They are created in a folder corresponding to its languaje. In my case, two folder were created:

- en
- es-MX

Inside each folder, ther was a single file: MySolution.resources.dll. Same name in both files. That way, at runtime, the application know which dll to use to load localized texts.

So you need those folders for using localized logic. If they're not present, the app could only use the texts from the default resource file.

In my case, again, when I tested my app, it worked great because the Debug folder had my MySolution.exe file and also the language folders. But it failed at prod environment because the main deployment was not considering those folders.

And also, the deployment configuration was set something like that:

```
-MainFolder
--MainApp.exe
--MainApp.configfile
--other files
--Folder
----MySolution.dll
----en
------MySolution.resources.dll
----es-MX
------MySolution.resources.dll
```

So I had to talk with the person in charge of deployments, so that could change to:

```
-MainFolder
--MainApp.exe
--MainApp.configfile
--other files
--MySolution.dll
--en
----MySolution.resources.dll
--es-MX
----MySolution.resources.dll
```

That way, my dll could load the language dlls, and the main executable could load everything ok. Happy ending.

I hope I was clear and it can help someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my answer based on personal experience: Build action "Embedded Resource" should work. All resources will be included.

```
Localization.Resources.Culture = culture; 
// "Overrides's the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
// resources lookups using this this strongly typed resource class."
```

I havent used this method personally, but this also means it could be changed back to `Localization.Resources.Culture = null;` without you knowing. Instead look into using `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;`. And heres a suggestion of a call if you intend to have an application with multiple languages:

```
public void SetUICulture(CultureInfo culture)
{
    CultureInfo savedUICultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = uiCultureInfo;

        // Do culture-specific stuff...
        this.lblStatusMessage.Content = Localization.Resources.OperationCancelled;
    }
    finally 
    { 
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = savedUICultureInfo
    }
}
```

This is also useful if you later on have several different resource files. In general I would suggest to take a look at what `CultureInfo` you're actually passing.